# Aggregate output by quarter/month in REPAST

Tags: repast-simphony

My REPAST simulation generates/displays (via Charts) an ouput for each day, I wonder if there is a way to aggregate and plot the results by month or quarter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you have something like this: each agent has some value that is aggregated via a data set and then displayed on a chart. For example, each agent has an energy value and the data set is the mean, or sum or some aggregate operation over all the agents' energy values. By default, the data is collected every tick, but you can set this to some other interval (e.g., every 30 ticks). If the value you are collecting from each agent can be aggregated in some way between those 30 ticks in each agent, then the data set will perform its aggregate operation on that 30 days worth of data.

Alternatively, and this is probably more common, if you need to do a non-daily analysis of your simulation output, typically you'd create a file sink that records the daily data and then operate on that data in some post-simulation step -- using Excel or R or whatever.